# looping through a file of tags seems to add a question mark

Tags: bash, git

I'm using bash and trying to loop through the lines of a file, to add git tags:

```
$ while read p; do  echo $p; git tag $p; done <NEW_TAGS.txt
```

Given the `NEW_TAGS.txt` has this content:

```
Test_V1_4.3
Test_V2_2.7
```

and each line ends with `<CR><LF>`, the result of the above line is this:

```
Test_V1_4.3
fatal: 'Test_V1_4.3?' is not a valid tag name.
Test_V2_2.7
fatal: 'Test_V2_2.7?' is not a valid tag name.
```

Where does the question marks come from? How do I remove them?

Alternatively, is there a better way to add a list of tags to git from a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is newline character. Linuxes and Unixes use `\n` when dos (Windows) systems use `\r\n` . Use `dos2unix` to change newline character.

```
[Alex@Normandy tmp]$ cat NEW_TAGS.txt 
Test_V1_4.3
Test_V2_2.7
[Alex@Normandy tmp]$ file NEW_TAGS.txt 
NEW_TAGS.txt: ASCII text
[Alex@Normandy tmp]$ while read p; do  echo $p; git tag $p; done <NEW_TAGS.txt
Test_V1_4.3
fatal: tag 'Test_V1_4.3' already exists
Test_V2_2.7
fatal: tag 'Test_V2_2.7' already exists
[Alex@Normandy tmp]$ unix2dos NEW_TAGS.txt 
unix2dos: converting file NEW_TAGS.txt to DOS format ...
[Alex@Normandy tmp]$ file NEW_TAGS.txt 
NEW_TAGS.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
[Alex@Normandy tmp]$ while read p; do  echo $p; git tag $p; done <NEW_TAGS.txt
Test_V1_4.3
fatal: 'Test_V1_4.3?' is not a valid tag name.
Test_V2_2.7
fatal: 'Test_V2_2.7?' is not a valid tag name.
```